# ruby Iteration or loop failing as expected

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to make chef-solo create the `knife.rb` files on the Jenkins slaves. So, I have the below in the attributes:

```
default['chef']['projects'] = ['ost', 'jt']
default['chef']['environments'] = ['dev', 'test', 'staging', 'production']
```

This is the block in the recipe:

```
node[:chef][:projects].each do |project|
  node[:chef][:environments].each do |env|
    template "#{node[:jenkins][:master][:home]}/.chef/knife-123#{project}-#{env}.rb" do
      source 'knife.rb.erb'
      owner 'jenkins'
      group 'jenkins'
      variables(
        :environment => env,
        :project => project == 'ost' ? '' : project
      )
    end
  end
end
```

And the template: `knife.rb.erb`

```
##This file is generated by Chef

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "jenkins-ro"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/jenkins-ro.pem"
validation_client_name   "123<%=@project%>-<%= @environment %>-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/123<%=@project%>-<%= @environment %>-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://CHEF_URL/organizations/123<%=@project%>-<%= @environment %>"
cache_type               'BasicFile'
cache_options( :path => "#{ENV['HOME']}/.chef/checksums" )
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
ssl_verify_mode          :verify_none
```

Now, with this, I am expecting 8 knife files namely and it does creates them.

```
1. knife-123ost-dev.rb
2. knife-123ost-test.rb
3. knife-123ost-staging.rb
4. knife-123ost-production.rb
5. knife-123jt-dev.rb
6. knife-123jt-test.rb
7. knife-123jt-staging.rb
8. knife-123jt-production.rb
```

The problem I am facing is with the below files. The other files for the project `ost` in the array works as expected.

```
5. knife-123jt-dev.rb
6. knife-123jt-test.rb
7. knife-123jt-staging.rb
8. knife-123jt-production.rb
```

doesn't have the value of the `project` *variable* populated in the template. Example, the file `knife-123jt-dev.rb`, looks like

```
##This file is generated by Chef

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "jenkins-ro"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/jenkins-ro.pem"
validation_client_name   "123-dev-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/123-dev-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://CHEF_URL/organizations/123-dev"
cache_type               'BasicFile'
cache_options( :path => "#{ENV['HOME']}/.chef/checksums" )
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
ssl_verify_mode          :verify_none
```

The expected files should look like the below.

123jt-dev

```
##This file is generated by Chef

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "jenkins-ro"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/jenkins-ro.pem"
validation_client_name   "123jt-dev-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/123jt-dev-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://CHEF_URL/organizations/123jt-dev"
cache_type               'BasicFile'
cache_options( :path => "#{ENV['HOME']}/.chef/checksums" )
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
ssl_verify_mode          :verify_none
```

123jt-test

```
##This file is generated by Chef

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "jenkins-ro"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/jenkins-ro.pem"
validation_client_name   "123jt-test-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/123jt-test-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://CHEF_URL/organizations/123jt-test"
cache_type               'BasicFile'
cache_options( :path => "#{ENV['HOME']}/.chef/checksums" )
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
ssl_verify_mode          :verify_none
```

123jt-staging

```
##This file is generated by Chef

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "jenkins-ro"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/jenkins-ro.pem"
validation_client_name   "123jt-staging-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/123jt-staging-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://CHEF_URL/organizations/123jt-staging"
cache_type               'BasicFile'
cache_options( :path => "#{ENV['HOME']}/.chef/checksums" )
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
ssl_verify_mode          :verify_none
```

123jt-production

```
##This file is generated by Chef

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "jenkins-ro"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/jenkins-ro.pem"
validation_client_name   "123jt-production-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/123jt-production-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://CHEF_URL/organizations/123jt-production"
cache_type               'BasicFile'
cache_options( :path => "#{ENV['HOME']}/.chef/checksums" )
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
ssl_verify_mode          :verify_none
```

Comment: Can I ask, what _should_ it look like?

Comment: The problem area is `:project => project == 'ost' ? '' : project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add parentheses.

```
:project => (project == 'ost' ? '' : project)
```

But I'd prefer:

```
:project => project unless project == 'ost'
```